# Hospitals and stuff you need

Tags: terminology

You know the long metal pole that the doctors give you when you break you leg what is it called?

Comment: It's worth noting that the term "crutch" is often used in a figurative sense for something that is used to, eg, support a company that is having financial difficulty.

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about one of these, it's called a ***crutch:***

[image: Aluminium adjustable crutch]

[Image via [Amazon.com](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B002VWJYTI)]

[image: Axillary (Under-Arm) Crutches]

[Image via [Wikipedia.com]](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File%3AAxillary_(underarm)_crutches.JPG)

Comment: Of course, they come in several styles.  More likely to be given out for temporary use is the [underarm style](https://www.walgreens.com/store/c/drive-medical-walking-crutches-with-underarm-pad-and-handgrip-pediatric/ID=prod6078239-product?ext=gooPLA_-_Home_Medical&pla&adtype=pla&kpid=sku6071663&sst=bbeec407-bbaf-4188-8a72-686da05b7bef).  And, of course, there's also the common cane.

Comment: The underarm style is [almost] never used in the UK. I don't think I've ever seen one.

Comment: I'd say that the underarm unit is a bit more common than the forearm crutch in the US.  The underarm crutch is what you'd get if you broke your leg or some such, as there is a much shorter "learning curve" for it.  The forearm crutch is more likely to be seen on someone with a  long-standing problem, as it is more convenient and effective over the long term.

Comment: My bride of 33+ years had her right knee replaced last year here in the US. The recommended hardware included a pair of underarm crutches plus two folding walkers: a light, adjustable-height tubular aluminum model, and a heavier tubular steel walker with four wheels, a small seat to stop and rest for a moment (i.e., not for "scooting" around) and hand brakes with locks. She was never offered forearm crutches; by the time they might have been useful, she was expected to be ambulating on her own. Ditto for everything Hot Licks said, but +1 to Andrew for providing not only the word but a photo!